# Null reference exception vs zero pointer access violation

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, null-pointer

Recently I read a book about c# and was quite confused with the statement that null reference exception is not the same as access violation in native code when the pointer is dereferenced. The meaning of this is quite unclear for me, couldn't you explain it, please?

Comment: When you say *in native code* did you actually mean to say in managed code? In native code access to a piece of memory (other than at null) for which your process doesn't have read/write access will also generate an AV. That should not normally happen for managed code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't answer precisely. In the book there was "in native code" but I think that equals to "in non-managed code".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In native code you access memory locations directly using pointers. If the pointer is 32 bit you can access around 4 billion virtual memory locations (2^32). However, not all virtual memory locations are mapped to physical memory and some of the locations are only mapped as read-only (e.g. code). If the native code tries to access a virtual memory location that is inaccessible you get an access violation on the CPU.

So access violations happens when you use an invalid pointer (either reading or writing the location pointed to by the pointer). The protection of the hardware memory manager helps you discover these errors by trapping the invalid access on the CPU and raising some form of error condition or exception. However, you can also have invalid pointers that results in access to memory locations that are accessible. Even though the access is invalid it is not discovered by the CPU and this can lead to memory corruption and other hard to fix bugs.

A common error in native code is to forget to initialize a pointer before using it. Often the pointer will then point to address 0 (also known as the null pointer). A strategy for catching this kind of error is to make the first page in the virtual address space (starting at address 0) inaccessible. When the invalid pointer is dereferenced you get an access violation. So in native code a null pointer error is reported as an access violation because address 0 is made inaccessible.

.NET executes on a virtual machine and does not provide pointers (unless you write *unsafe* code). The concept of access violation does not apply to .NET code. However, a .NET reference can be uninitialized (e.g. null). The virtual machine will throw a `NullReferenceException` when a null reference is dereferenced. Conceptually, this is somewhat similar to how native code null pointer errors are reported as access violations as described above but the concepts and mechanisms are different.

Comment: Thank you a lot, couldn't you only clarify two points:
1. AccessViolationException is caught on CPU level (previous) and NullReferenceException on virtual machine level, yes?

Comment: 2. "However, you can also have invalid pointers that results in access to memory locations that are accessible." - couldn't you clarify what do you mean in "invalid pointers" here?

Comment: @EvgeniyKluchikov: In C you can `malloc` a buffer and then `free` it. If you keep the pointer after calling `free` it is an invalid pointer because you are not supposed to use it anymore. If you later write to the location of the pointer you have made a mistake and the heap may become corrupted because you are overwriting important data. However, you do not get an access violation because your code has full access to that location but the bug may surface later when your program crashes in unexpected ways. So all invalid pointer bugs does not surface as access violations.

Comment: @EvgeniyKluchikov: Re: `AccessViolationException`. This is a .NET exception because some native code called by .NET can lead to access violations. This is converted to an `AccessViolationException` but in managed-only code you should not expect this exception. _Access violoations_ is a concept that applies to computers with memory management. It is a hardware feature and is reported by special mechanisms that depends on the CPU. On an Intel x86 the mechanism is an _interrupt_. On Windows this is converted to a structured exception which then in .NET is converted to `AccessViolationException`.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be very interesting. Couldn't you advice a good book about computer architecture than to know more about such and other interesting things?

Answer (score 1):

A `NullReferenceException` happens when you dereference an object reference that is `null`. `null` is a special value on the CLR which means "no object". It does *not* mean null pointer. In practice it is a null pointer but that is an implementation detail.

For managed code, an `AccessViolationException` makes no sense because *there are no pointers* in managed code. Don't confuse the conceptual level with the current implementation.

Comment: I.e. it is only conceptual difference for _current_ implementation?

Comment: No this is permanent because the conceptual model and the physical implementation are two things. Never does the CLI specification talk about implementation details (except maybe very rare, but I'm not aware of any such place). If the two models happen to be closely aligned (like they are now) this is a coincidence.

Comment: You might be interested to know that a nullref exception is indeed implemented by dereferencing a null pointer. The CLR then catches the access violation and translates it into a `NullReferenceException`. But all of this is invisible to managed code.

Comment: Thank you a lot, yes, it is interesting for me.